# Parsing an XML to a tableview

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I'm really new to developing on Android. I started learning developing due to an application we need to make. I also have a deadline. 
So, I wonder if anyone could help this hopeless rookie out :P That'd be so great.

I need the values of the keywords (lag, kamper, mal, poeng, maldiff, status, posisjon, hb, malH, MalB, E, V, U, T, J, kn, id) to be put into a tableview. Not all of them but many.

If someone got a guide or tutorial that a newbie could follow, it would be greatly appreciated.
Or if someone could set it up for me so I could fill in the rest.

I know I'm way over my head with this stuff but if there's any chance I can get it done, I will try.

Here's an URL to a forum I posted the XML in.

http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/parsing-xml-requesting-guide-for-new-beginner-t55538.html

How do I add XML file? Copy-paste doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

use jaxp library to parse xml. Inthat xpath concept is there. using this we can easily parse xml.

Comment: Id love to do that if understod what you ment by it :P As i said above i am rly new to developing. And making my way trough the newbostons tutorial vids.

Comment: try to read this link http://jaxp.java.net/1.3/article/jaxp-1_3-article.html you will get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your problem then according to me there is no method to show data in        `TableView` directly while parsing the xml file, you need to parse XML file and store data(say key - value pair or in bean class) and then you need to write code to set your `TableView` with parsed vales.

Comment: Okey thx. So I parse and store the information. Than setup a tableview. And code each slot to a key in the tableview.
The link above i got provided, I can run with that?
http://www.anddev.org/other-coding-problems-f5/parsing-xml-requesting-guide-for-new-beginner-t55538.html